# "port forwarding": redirect calls to webservice at port 8081 to port 80

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-server-2008, apache2

a colleague of mine wrote a webservice that runs on port 8081 of our Windows 2008 Server.
He uses the class ServiceHost, afaik this means its a standalone host (no IIS or ASP involvement). Note: I'm new into WCF ;)

Now there are some issues with clients behind a firewall blocking the requests to remote port 8081 of our server (where the webservice runs). The easiest solution would be: run the webservice host at port 80 ... But: there is also a Apache 2.2 webserver running on the Windows Server, hosting some websites. By default it runs on port 80.

My solution after some researching: use a virtual host to route requests to a virtual host (lets say http://webservice.[hostname]:80) to the webservice host (http://[hostname]:8081).

Is this a good idea? Can Apache handle forwards to standalone webservice hosts?
It would be nice if someone could lead me on to the right track :)

Best regards,
Niels

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have Apache and IIS listening on the same port, but hopefully someone proves me wrong below.

Comment: BTW, is there a technical reason you are running Apache on a Windows server?  IIS could save you much pain and effort.

Comment: Well, no technical reason afaik, historical reasons. There is a mediawiki, wordpress blogs and so on. I will check how to run them on a IIS.

I wont run apache and IIS on the same port. I is planed to use two physical servers for webservices and webpages in the future, or at least virtualization. But I need a workaround now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to get a different IP address to run the WCF host on. Then, you could have both listening on the same port but different IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, we ordered a second IP adress for the server. I will check this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your Apache server is your forward facing server and you want the requests to be forwarded to your internal service/IIS you should look at `mod_proxy` and configuring a [reverse proxy](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies).